# Semantic GraphQL query complains that type is Unknown for multimedia schema type

Tags: content-delivery, sdl-tridion

The query that was working fine, but now I am getting error "Validation error of type UnknownType: Unknown type Image @ 'page/regions/components/events/image'". I had same issue with the Button too, but after Updating Schema name back and forth, saving and republishing components. the Button ( the button inline fragment query **... on Button** in the query) is working fine. For image the issue could not be resolved even after following same procedure.
Please help!

```
  query ($namespaceId: Int!, $publicationId: Int!, $pageId: Int!) {
  page(
    namespaceId: $namespaceId
    publicationId: $publicationId
    pageId: $pageId
  ) {
    title
    url
    regions {
      name
      components {
        ... on EventGroup {
          templateName
          titleStr
          events {
            ... on Event {
              templateName
              titleStr
              schedule
              location
              detail
              note
              image {
                ... on Image {
                  variants {
                    edges {
                      node {
                        path
                        downloadUrl
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              buttons {
                ... on Button {
                  templateName
                  label
                  linkTarget
                  externalUrl
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        ... on ImageLink {
          templateName
          externalUrl
          linkTarget
          image {
            ... on Image {
              variants {
                edges {
                  node {
                    path
                    downloadUrl
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Error :

```
{
    "data": null,
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Validation error of type UnknownType: Unknown type Image @ 'page/regions/components/events/image'",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 24,
                    "column": 24,
                    "sourceName": null
                }
            ],
            "description": "Unknown type Image",
            "validationErrorType": "UnknownType",
            "queryPath": [
                "page",
                "regions",
                "components",
                "events",
                "image"
            ],
            "errorType": "ValidationError",
            "extensions": null,
            "path": null
        },
        {
            "message": "Validation error of type UnknownType: Unknown type Image @ 'page/regions/components/image'",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 51,
                    "column": 20,
                    "sourceName": null
                }
            ],
            "description": "Unknown type Image",
            "validationErrorType": "UnknownType",
            "queryPath": [
                "page",
                "regions",
                "components",
                "image"
            ],
            "errorType": "ValidationError",
            "extensions": null,
            "path": null
        }
    ]
}
```